# How to download existing SqlCe Db and use in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

understand an existing SQlCe Db which has data in it can be copied into project and used later on. Now , I have a different approach. can I download the SqlCe Db with Data from a website into Wndows phone.

I use this : BackgroundTransferRequest

```
void Download()
{
    btr = new BackgroundTransferRequest(remoteVideoUri, localDownloadUri);
    btr.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowCellularAndBattery;
    BackgroundTransferService.Add(btr);
    btr.TransferProgressChanged += new EventHandler(btr_TransferProgressChanged);
    btr.TransferStatusChanged += new EventHandler(btr_TransferStatusChanged);
}
```

Questions:

1. Where do I download it to IsolatedStorage?  to : @isostore?
2. Will override the existing SqlCe Db with the same name? or create it like  name(copy).sdf ?
3. I think these insert/Update/Delete SQL operation can be applied to it.
4. Is there a way to check the Filesize of SqlCe Db BEFORE downloading it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) All local paths for background transfers must be within the isolated storage for your application within a root directory named “/shared/transfers”.

2) I believe you will get an error if the download file already exists locally.

3) Not sure what your question is.

4) You can check the BackgroundTransferRequest.TotalBytesToReceive property although this relies on the content length header being provided by the server.  Also this isn't actually available until the download begins.  If you want find out the size before you do anything you will have to code that yourself.

Comment: (1) Not sure abt this. To use Db, it must be in isostore.   (2) I think it should not. But I am not sure. I need positive answer. (3) I mean if I can use these SQL operation on the downloaded DB. Will it change to readOnly mode. (4) It will be better if I can know before hand. How?

Comment: 1) /shared/transfers is in isolated storage and so will work fine. Although it is good practice to move it out of that folder once it has downloaded.  2)Try it and see for yourself  3)No it will not be changed to readonly.  4) If you don't own the server then there is nothing you can do to find the size, other than rely on TotalBytesToReceive, however if this isn't provided by the server you're out of luck.